# Overriding css file in theme.info not working as expected

Tags: theming, .info

I am trying to remove nice menus css, as per the notes in my Zen theme .info file.
I have added the below to the info file, and I haven't provided replacements in my theme so they should be removed.

```
stylesheets[all][] = nice_menus.css
stylesheets[all][] = nice_menus_default.css
```

However they are still being imported. Cache cleared.

Thanks

[image]

EDIT: I'm aware this can be achieved using hooks, but would like to do it at theme .info file level, unless I am mistaken and it is not possible to remove contrib module .css in the theme .info file.

Comment: which version of drupal are you using?

Comment: Drupal version 7.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the css file of particular module

```
function MY_MODULE_css_alter(&$css) {   
unset($css[drupal_get_path('module', 'views') . '/css/views.css']);
$css = array_diff_key($css, $exclude);  
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this hook, as I haven't time to work out why the .info file solution isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try disable/enable theme. Yes it likes a trick. It seems info files are parsed when modules/themes are enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove(alter) css files with [hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7), here is a simple example:

```
function MY_MODULE_OR_THEME_css_alter(&$css) {
    // dpm($css);
    unset($css[drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.menus.css']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes I am aware of that but I don't want to load it, just to unload it. I'd rather not load it in the first place, which can be done in .info file.